# What is the status of forced HTTPS everywhere (Strict transport security) via DNS? I only see the July 2010 draft

Tags: web-application, tls, dns, configuration, dnssec

I'm trying to find the most recent RFC on [HSTS in DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Applicability) (or rather said DNSSEC), but can only find [this year old one in expired draft status](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hodges-strict-transport-sec-02)

Where can I find the most current guidance on STS in DNS? If it's not available yet, how can I keep informed of the latest developments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the link in the header: [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-06) dated Mar 2012 replaces the one you linked, and expires in Sep 2012.

See also [the websec working group](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/websec/).

Comment: I think that question was about current status of a "more workable solution can be achieved by including HSTS data inside DNS records, and accessing them securely via DNSSEC" (from wikipedia), not about current status of HSTS itself

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBotalov outside of the header route, or the dnssec route, *is* there a better way you know of?